# Primary key and Attributes

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I came across a rather stumping question out of the blue. In SQL, would a primary key be considered an attribute to a particular entity? I've done some research and although it is a specific key to uniquely identify an attribute, would it also be included as an attribute to a particular entity?  Part of me says yes and part of me says no since it is just a key that specifies an attribute. Any advice would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

If primary key is formed out of the attributes of the entity then its a part of the entity. In case of surrogate key its not a part of the entity but associated with it.
Hope I got the intent of your question.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So if the primary key is listed with an attribute to begin with, then it is part of the entity? So I would list something like all attributes plus primary key as all of the attributes?

Comment: The way you want to display (list or see) the data is independent of the primary key. The function of primary key is to uniquely identify the data. The way you want to imagine the display is up to you.